# Java: JButton opening another JFrame that I can input into

Tags: java, swing

I want to be able to click a JButton from my JFrame which opens up another window and in this 2nd window, I want to be able to input something into a text field on that window and get the information from that text field.

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Click Here!");
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
if (event.getSource() == myButton) {
// open the new window }
```

I know how to define the components of this new JFrame, but how will I write an actionPerformed event for that new window since nesting modules isn't allowed?

Comment: What step are you stuck on? Opening the second window (which should be a modal dialog by the way)? Getting information from that 2nd window? And please show a bit more code if possible.

Comment: Well I'm not completely sure about how to go about defining the second window (which I will need to interact with), do I use another JFrame or is there another method? Would I put the interactions with the new window in the same actionPerformed method or would it work if I defined another actionPerformed method in the same class?

Comment: If you only need a text field in a new window, maybe an input dialog from the `JOptionPane` class might just suit your needs. If you really need a new window, then follow HovercraftFullOfEels's advice and create a modal dialog (JDialog).

Comment: @lootu thanks, JOptionPane is the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Note for future reference that a JOptionPane is actually nothing more than a specialized form of a modal dialog window.

Comment: Is there a way to customize the contents of the modal dialog window? For instance if I wanted 2 text fields in the pop up window (so it can take 2 inputs)? What if I wanted to change the "OK"/"Cancel" buttons to have different labels and/or behave differently?

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the **`{}`** button at the top of the message posting editing form.

Comment: @user2908849: a modal dialog (JDialog) or a JOptionPane, like a JFrame, can hold a JPanel that has the most complex GUI that you can imagine including nesting other JPanels that use whatever layouts are necessary and that contain multiple components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to customize the contents of the modal dialog window? For instance if I wanted 2 text fields in the pop up window (so it can take 2 inputs)? What if I wanted to change the "OK"/"Cancel" buttons to have different labels and/or behave differently?

A modal dialog (JDialog) or a JOptionPane, like a JFrame, can hold a JPanel that has the most complex GUI that you can imagine including nesting other JPanels that use whatever layouts are necessary and that contain multiple components. For example, the following code creates JOptionPane that displays a JPanel that holds a number of JTextFields, all extractable after the JOptionPane returns:

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComplexDialogPanel extends JPanel {
   public static final String[] LABEL_TEXTS = { "Last Name", "First Name",
         "Address", "City", "State", "Zip" };
   public static final int COLS = 8;
   private Map<String, JTextField> labelFieldMap = new HashMap<>();

   public ComplexDialogPanel() {
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      for (int i = 0; i < LABEL_TEXTS.length; i++) {
         String labelTxt = LABEL_TEXTS[i];
         add(new JLabel(labelTxt), createGbc(0, i));

         JTextField textField = new JTextField(COLS);
         labelFieldMap.put(labelTxt, textField);
         add(textField, createGbc(1, i));
      }

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enter User Information"));
   }

   public String getText(String labelText) {
      JTextField textField = labelFieldMap.get(labelText);
      if (textField != null) {
         return textField.getText();
      } else {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(labelText);
      }
   }

   public static GridBagConstraints createGbc(int x, int y) {
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.gridx = x;
      gbc.gridy = y;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = gbc.weightx;
      if (x == 0) {
         gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
         gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
         gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 8);
      } else {
         gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
         gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
         gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
      }
      return gbc;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ComplexDialogPanel mainPanel = new ComplexDialogPanel();

      int optionType = JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION;
      int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
      Icon icon = null;
      String[] options = { "Submit", "Cancel" };
      Object initialValue = options[0];
      int reply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, mainPanel,
            "Get User Information", optionType, messageType, icon, options,
            initialValue);
      if (reply == 0) {
         System.out.println("Selections:");
         for (String labelText : LABEL_TEXTS) {
            System.out.printf("%12s: %s%n", labelText,
                  mainPanel.getText(labelText));
         }

      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this was the type of thing I was looking for. I'm curious why extends JPanel over JFrame? Also which line(s) describe what the "Submit" and "Cancel" button do?